# Не нужно ли поставить тире в предложении перед "одни"?

Tags: пунктуация

*...что условия контрактов на строительство дорог в Крыму, одни из самых жестких по всей России.*

Answer (score 3):

Да никакого знака не нужно - ни запятой, ни тире.

И правила на "почему не ставится знак" я привести не могу: не на все случаи они есть. (Есть, к примеру, на ложные вводные или на оборот, стоящий перед определяемым словом, - но не на все же!)

Comment: ну не знаааю, когда я читаю это предложение, тире у меня прямо-таки в интонации заметно, если можно так выразиться.

Comment: Не все интонационные паузы отображаются на письме. Вот на отсутствующее правило я сослаться не могу, но Вам же проще: есть тире - есть правило, его обосновывающее.

Comment: @ParanoidGingerbread, давайте выкинем, какие именно условия, считая, что и так понятно из контекста. Так Вы всё равно поставите тире в этом случае? Например: "Он сказал, что условия контрактов одни из самых жёстких по всей России". Просто случаи с уточнением и без вроде ничем не отличаются с точки зрения постановки знаков.

Comment: Не знаю, прав я или нет, но я привык к тому, что когда ставят тире, то само понятие **определяется, а не характеризуется.**

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, я, наверное, не совсем точно выразилась. Имела в виду, если, к примеру, предложения будет таким: "что условия контрактов на строительство дорог в Крыму, одни из самых жестких по всей России, вызывают серьезные затруднения в реализации новой политики" или что-то вроде.

Comment: @ParanoidGingerbread, ну, такое предложение совсем другое дело. У Вас, конечно, д. б. с двух сторон запятые (может, и тире, не знаю). Просто у flossy другое предложение: то, что условия одни из самых жёстких, утверждается, а не уточняется. По крайней мере, я сделал такой вывод, п. ч. **в конце стоит точка.**

Answer (score 2):

"...что условия контрактов на строительство дорог в Крыму **—** одни из самых жестких по всей России" либо же "...что условия контрактов на строительство дорог в Крыму одни из самых жестких по всей России". Тире здесь факультативно, на мой взгляд, и служит скорее для акцентирования на второй части предложения.

Answer (score 0):

..что условия контрактов на строительство дорог в Крыму - одни из самых жестких по всей России. Я думаю, что тире здесь нужно. Подлежащее - условия контрактов, сказуемое - одни из самых жёстких (синтаксически неделимое словосочетание).     Тире не ставится, если между подлежащим и сказуемым (номинативным словосочетанием) стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица. Ничего этого я здесь не увидела.Следовательно, тире следует поставить.